# How to get the images from the posts

Tags: wordpress

I have implemented my blog using wordpress and in my posts iam directly posts the images but while if I want to display them they are not retrieving.

I have used `the_content()` then it was displaying the image with the remaining content in that post can anyone suggest me How to retrieve those images..??Thanx in advance

Comment: You are posting the image from the dashboard or manually coding and adding it? And what exactly do you want to achieve, could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: iam adding images through dashboard and while adding posts iam browsing the images through gallery and posting it on the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting images in the **content area**,so obviously it will be appearing as content on front end.
You need to set the images as `Featured image` or add them by using `Add media` option at the top of `text editor`.

**For retrieving the `image` from Featured image:**(Single image)

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full')
```

**For retrieving the `image` from Add media:**(Multiple images)

```
$img_small = get_children('order=ASC&orderby=menu_order&post_type=attachment&post_parent=' . $post->ID);

foreach ($img_small as $imagesmall) {
 $attachmentID = $imagesmall->ID;
 $attachmentURL = wp_get_attachment_url($attachmentID);
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=<?php echo $attachmentURL; ?>&w=365&h=280&iar=1">alt="Image" />
}
```

Comment: What is $post..??iam using while (have_posts()) : the_post(); loop for displaying the posts

Comment: you need to define `global $post` in your header.php it returns the element of the current post in which you are standing,where as have_post is like a loop like how many post you have it will display all of them

Comment: Ok dude I got this....we can also use $post = get_post() in the while loop right..??

Comment: find this link
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post
 to get best explanation.